# I've been following the Auth0 ionic app tutorial having challenges with the idToken it returns undefined

Tags: angularjs, auth0

i'm getting this error- ReferenceError: idToken is not defined at controllers.js:99 at auth0-angular4.js:619. what could be the issue with my tokens?

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth, $state, $timeout, Auth, store, $location, auth, $rootScope, jwtHelper) {

  $scope.login = function() {
    auth.signin({
      authParams: {
        scope: 'openid offline-access',
        device: 'Mobile device'
      }

    }, function(profile, token, accessToken, state, refreshToken) {
      store.set('store', profile);
      store.set('token', idToken);
      store.set('refreshToken', refreshToken);
      auth.getToken({
        api: 'firebase'
      }).then(function(delegate) {
        store.set('firebaseToken', delegate.id_token);
        $state.go('tabsController.pendingTasks');

      }, function(error) {

      })
    })
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {
      if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
        var token = store.get('token');
        if (token) {
          if (!jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
            auth.authenticate(store.get('profile'), token);
          } else {
            // Use the refresh token we had
            auth.refreshIdToken(refreshToken).then(function(idToken) {
              store.set('token', idToken);
              auth.authenticate(store.get('profile'), token);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });

  }


})
```

this occurs after calling the login() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling

`store.set('token', idToken);`

on line 12 of your sample code, but the parameter being passed in to the function (on line 10) is named `token`.

So try changing line 12 to

`store.set('token', token);`

Comment: ok thanks, i did that it worked but now im getting other error  "POST https://muzij.auth0.com/delegation 400 (Bad Request)"

Comment: That status code in itself does not say much. You need to inspect the network traffic and look at the request to see the actual request and response to try and figure out what is happening. Perhaps the best would be to contact Auth0 support and supply a sample application which demonstrates the issue. To figure out the problem on SO from an isolated little piece of code can be difficult. For support options see https://auth0.com/support

Comment: Also that call to `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart',....` should be defined in the `run` function of your application module. See https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-ionic-samples/blob/quickstart_v3/03-User%20Profile/www/app/app.js for an example